# How to do mongodb ACID transaction in django with djongo as database backend?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, djongo

I'm using MongoDB in Django with Django as database back end.
Right now it does not support ACID transactions but Mongo and PyMongo do. Is there a way to tweak this library to support ACID transactions with using ORM and without making queries by PyMongo?

Answer (score -1):

As a first step you can change the *isolation level* of MongoDB, cf 
https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/, default isolationlevel is `READ UNCOMMITED` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/)

For improving atomicity cf https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/ , for improving consistency cf https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/